# Joomla Template support for Frontendediting

Tags: joomla-3.4, front-end

What do I need to do to make my self-written template for Joomla support frontend editing?

Atm when I enable frontend editing I do get the edit button, but when I click it, it does not open anything, just reloads the page. 
I cannot find any tutorials or figure out yet how the Joomla templates do it. It is a rather time critical, so any hint and help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Edit: The problem seems to be the ldap plugin, issue isn't solved, but at least identified.

Comment: If you set Protostar as the default template and try to edit something via the frontend, does it work? Also, have you made any changes to any core Joomla files?

Comment: And did you gave create permission to your user groups (if the front-end users do not belong to author group) in global configuration?

Comment: I logged in the frontend as superuser, the permissions should work out, and the edit button is visible after all (for the super user, not the merely registered users). But alas the protostar template seems to has the same problem indeed. I did not alter core files myself, but maybe a colleque did some html overwrites.

Comment: So better, remove those overrides and try.

Comment: I did try removing the overrides. All it does though is altering the appearance of the edit button. I start to think the problem is not rooted in the template but somewhere else, since the protostar template has the same problem. If I had a better understanding of how the frontend editing is realized I might be able to figure it out, but the project is too complex and migrated from outdated joomla versions, it'll be hard to track down every change and difference towards a standart install.

Comment: Can you try clearing your Joomla cache and also your browser cache? Then check if you have any 3rd party plugins and could possibly alter the behavior of front-end editing

Comment: Alrighty It looks like the problem was the LPAD authentification. After disabling the plug in it worked (aside from formating issues), the fun thing is, after I enabled the plugin again it kept working.